# How to Insert form values into MySQL database without refreshing the form and losing the field values of the form?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Hi,

I have a form and I want to insert its values into a MySQL database without refreshing the form and losing its values. 
By clicking on the 'print' button the user should be able to generate a report from the data they entered in the form, but the form keeps refreshing on submit. So I would like to know how I can store the data in the database without having the form refreshed (i.e. using Ajax)?

Below is my form code:

```
  <div class="commentpost"></div>
    <form name="entry" id="entry" method="POST" action="">
    <table border="1" bgcolor="Silver">
        <tr>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                <h2><b>Candidate Entry</b><h2>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
               Code 
            </td>
            <td>
             <input type="text"  name="vouchno" value="New" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" readonly="readonly" size="8" maxlength="8">
            Date
          <input type="text" id="vouchdt" name="vouchdt" id="popupDatepicker" tabindex="1" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['vouchdt']) ? $_POST['vouchdt'] : ''); ?>"></td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id='councode' name="councode" size="1" maxlength="2" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['councode']) ? $_POST['councode'] : ''); ?>"><input type="text" id="counvouch" name="counvouch" size="8" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['counvouch']) ? $_POST['counvouch'] : ''); ?>" maxlength="8">
          <div id="cam">

          </div>
                <input type=button value="Configure..." onClick="webcam.configure()">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type=button value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">

        <div id="upload_results" style="background-color:#eee;"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Name
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : ''); ?>" maxlength="40" size="45" tabindex="2">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Address
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea name="add" id="add" row="3" cols="40" tabindex="3">
                   <?php echo (isset($_POST['vouchdt']) ? $_POST['vouchdt'] : ''); ?>
                </textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                City
            </td>
            <td>
               <input type="text" id="city" name="city" size="20" maxlength="20"  value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : ''); ?>" tabindex="4">
             Pin
                <input type="text" id="pin" name="pin" size="6" maxlength="6" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['pin']) ? $_POST['pin'] : ''); ?>" tabindex="5">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Nationality
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="ntn" name="ntn" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['ntn']) ? $_POST['ntn'] : ''); ?>" size="10" maxlength="10" tabindex="6">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Mobile No 
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="mob" name="mob" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['mob']) ? $_POST['mob'] : ''); ?>" tabindex="7">
            </td>
         </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Date of Birth
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="dob" name="dob" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['dob']) ? $_POST['dob'] : ''); ?>" id="popupDatepicker2" tabindex="8">
                </td>
                <td>
                    Age
                </td>
                <td width="9px">
                    <input type="text" id="age" name="age" size="3" maxlength="3" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['age']) ? $_POST['age'] : ''); ?>" tabindex="9">
                </td>
                <td width="10px">
                    Sex
                </td>
                <td>
                             <select id="sex" name="sex" tabindex="12">
                                 <?php 
                                 if(isset($_POST[sex])==m){
                                 ?>
                                     <option   value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['sex']) ? $_POST['sex'] : ''); ?>">Male</option>":
                                <?php }else{?>
                                         <option   value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['sex']) ? $_POST['sex'] : ''); ?>">Female</option>":
                                <?php }?>         
                            <option value="m">Male</option>
                            <option value="f">Female</option>                           
                            </select>                

                </td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Religion
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="rel" name="rel" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['rel']) ? $_POST['rel'] : ''); ?>" size="20" maxlength="20" tabindex="11">

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Martial Status
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select id ="status" name="status" tabindex="12">
                            <option value="">--select--</option>
                            <option value="1">Married</option>
                            <option value="2">Unmarried</option>                           
                            </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Passport No.
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" value="" size="15" maxlength="15" tabindex="13">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Place of Issue
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <input type="text" id="poi" name="poi" size="20" maxlenght-20 tabindex="14">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Date of Issue
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <input type="text" id="doi" name="doi" id="popupDatepicker4" tabindex="15">

                    </td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          Profession
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input type="text" id="prof" name="prof" size="20" maxlenght="20" value="" tabindex="16">
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          Amount
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input type="text" id="amt" name="amt" value="" size ="8" onblur="calculateText()" style="background-color:transparent; color:blue; text-align:right" tabindex="17">
                      </td>                                            
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          Payment
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <select id="pay" name="pay" tabindex="12">
                            <option value="">--select--</option>
                            <option value="f">Full</option>                           
                            <option value="p">Part</option>
                            <option value="n">None</option>

                            </select>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          Received
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input type="text" id="resc" name="resc" value="" size ="8" onblur="calculateText()" style="background-color:transparent; color:green; text-align:right" tabindex="18">
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                  <td>
                      Agent
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <input type="tetx" id="agnt" name="agnt" value="" size="40" maxlength="40" tabindex="21">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      Balance
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <input type="text" id="bal" name="bal"  readonly="readonly" value="" size ="8" style="background-color:transparent; color:red; text-align:right" onblur="calculateText()" tabindex="19">
                  </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          Mofa No.
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input type="text" id="mofa" name="mofa" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" tabindex="22">
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          Remarks
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input type="text" id="rem" name="rem" size="60" maxlength="60" value="" tabindex="23">
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <table border="0" align="center">
                      <tr>

                          <td>
                              <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save"><input type="hidden" name="task" value="addComments" />

                          <td>
                              <input type="submit" name="print" value="Print">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <input type="submit" name="close" value="Cancel">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <input type="reset" name="Add" value="Add">
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                  </table>
    </table>    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $("#entry").submit(function(){

        ctask        = this.task.value;    
        cvouchdt     = this.vouchdt.value;
        ccouncde     = this.councode.value;
        ccounvouch   = this.counvouch.value;
        cname        = this.name.value;
        ccity        = this.city.value;
        cpin         = this.pin.value;
        cntn         = this.ntn.value;
        cmob         = this.mob.value;
        cdob         = this.dob.value;
        cage         = this.age.value;
        csex         = this.sex.value;
        crel         = this.rel.value;
        cstatus      = this.status.value;
        cpass        = this.pass.value;
        crel         = this.rel.value;
        cpoi         = this.poi.value;
        cdoi         = this.doi.value;
        cprof        = this.prof.value;
        camt         = this.amt.value;
        cpay         = this.pay.value;
        cpass        = this.pass.value;
        crecd        = this.recd.value;
        cagnt        = this.agnt.value;
        cbal         = this.bal.value;
        cmofa        = this.mofa.value;
        crem        = this.rem.value;        


        save    = this.save;

        if(cname=="" || ccounvouch=="" || ccouncde=="") { $("#errAll").html('<p>Invalid Captcha. Please try again.</p>');  }

        $.post("submit.php", {task: ctask, name: cname, email: cemail, url: curl, message: cmessage}, function(data){
            if(data=='0') { $("#errAll").html('<p>Please don\'t leave the requierd fields.</p>'); }
            else if(data=='1') { $("#errAll").html('<p>Invalid Email Address, Please try again.</p>'); }
            else { submitter.value="Value Saved"; save.disabled=false;} //$(data).appendTo($(".commentpost")); }
        });

        return false;

    });
});
</script>
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
//include_once( 'config.php' );
require("includes/dbconnect.php");

$getmaxvou = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(`vouchno`) as `maxid` FROM `candidate` ") or die(mysql_error());
$max  = mysql_fetch_array($getmaxvou);
$maxv =$max["maxid"]+1; 

if(isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task'] == 'addComments') 
{
     $a = 1;
    $date      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["vouchdt"]);
    $date      = strtotime($date);
    $date      = date('Y-m-d',$date);
    $cname     = trim($_POST["name"]);
    $add       = trim($_POST["add"]);
    $city      = trim($_POST["city"]);
    $pin       = trim($_POST["pin"]);
    $nations   = trim($_POST["ntn"]);
    $mob       = trim($_POST["mob"]);
    $dob       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["dob"]);
    $dob       = strtotime($dob);
    $dob       = date('Y-m-d',$dob);
    $age       = trim($_POST["age"]);
    $sex       = trim($_POST["sex"]);
    $rel       = trim($_POST["rel"]);
    $pass      = trim($_POST["pass"]);
    $status    = trim($_POST["status"]);
    $poi       = trim($_POST["poi"]);
    $doi       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["doi"]);
    $doi       = strtotime($doi);
    $doi       = date('Y-m-d',$doi);
    $prof      = trim($_POST["prof"]);
    $amt       = trim($_POST["amt"]);
    $pay       = trim($_POST["pay"]);
    $bal       = trim($_POST["bal"]);
    $recd      = trim($_POST["resc"]);
    $agnt      = trim($_POST["agnt"]);
    $mofa      = trim($_POST["mofa"]);
    $rem       = trim($_POST["rem"]);
    $councode  = trim($_POST["councode"]);
    $counvouch = trim($_POST["counvouch"]);



 {     

     if (isset($_POST["code"])) {
            $sql_check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM candiidate WHERE code ='$councode' AND  counvouch='$counvouch'");

            if (mysql_num_rows($sql_check) > 0) {
                $a = 0;
                print '<script type="text/javascript">';
                print 'alert("Code Already Exist For the Country")';
                PRINT '</script>';
            }
        }
        if($a ==1){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `candidate`(vouchno, vouchdt, `name`, `add`, `city`, `pin`, `nationality`, mobile, dob, `religion`, `passport`, `profession`, amt, recd, bal, payment, `agent`, `mofa`, `age`, `gender`, `martial`, `poi`, doi, councode, counvouch, `rem` )
            Values
                   ('$maxv',  '$date', '$cname', '$add', '$city', '$pin', '$nations', '$mob', '$dob', '$rel', '$pass', '$prof', '$amt', '$recd', '$bal', '$pay', '$agnt', '$mofa', '$age', '$sex', '$status', '$poi', '$doi', '$councode', '$counvouch', '$rem' )") or die(mysql_error());  

        echo ' <div class="commentbox">
                <div class="commentboxt">Value Inserted </div>
                                </div>';
    }
 }
}?>
```

Comment: Nobody will read that block of code. If you want to be helped, do some work before asking.

Comment: i did my values are coming into the fields but the arent saving into my database and even the datepicker is not working sir

Comment: Are you able to insert into database? If so. Then change input type submit to button. On click of button call your ajax or javascript function to insert data into database.

Comment: no sir m not being able to save it a deven the datepicker function is not working

Comment: Are you actually asking a question here? - If so WHAT are you asking? - have a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: @kumail - I would suggest to reduce the code examples to just snippets relating only to your question. An overload like this could demotivate people from answering the question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change form tag to

```
<form name="entry" id="entry" method="GET" action="javascript:">
```

that will stop the page from refreshing.

Then look into jquery ajax http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
For example.

```
    var string ="FORMVALUE1=" + $('#FORMVALUE1ID').val() + "FORMVALUE2=" + $('#FORMVALUE2ID').val() + "REAPEAT FOR ALL YOUR VALUES";

    $.ajax({  
    type: "GET",  
    url: "YOURPHPFILE.php",
    data: string,  
    });
```

Then just get the form values in the php file by using `$_GET['FORMVALUE1'];`

Answer (score 0):

You first seperate your PHP file where you insert or do some action.

PHP Action File: YourPHPPostFile.php
HTML File: index.html or whatever name you have.

Then in PHP file write all your code but in the begining add check that is

```
if(isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task'] == 'addComments') 
{//Your all PHP Code here}
```

On the other hand in your html file make a AJAX request to this file and use POST Method in AJAX request and include your data within Request Parameters.

One more thing if you don't want to lose your Form data which is filled you can use:

```
<form name="entry" id="entry" method="GET" onsubmit="calltoAjax();return false;">
```

Now whenever user submit form then it will not reset the form and data also stored in your database.

Thanks,